# RoR encode mail subject from KOI8-R to UTF-8 doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem whit decode mail subject in Ruby on Rails.
I try encode mail subject: "=?KOI8-R?B?z9Qg09XQxdLXwcraxdLB?="

```
<% if /koi8-r/ =~ msg.subject or /KOI8-R/ =~ msg.subject %>
<% subj = msg.subject.gsub(/=\?.*\?B\?/, '') %>
<% subj = subj.gsub(/\?=/, '') %>
<%= Base64.decode64(subj).force_encoding("KOI8-R").encode("UTF-8", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"?")
```

And get error:
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

But if i do that in irb, all work fine:

```
2.0.0p247 :009 > subj = "z9Qg09XQxdLXwcraxdLB"
 => "z9Qg09XQxdLXwcraxdLB"
2.0.0p247 :010 >  Base64.decode64(subj).force_encoding("KOI8-R").encode("UTF-8", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"?")
 => "от супервайзера"
2.0.0p247 :011 >
```

Why my code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

As an example:

```
# My starting string:
rus = "привет"

# generate fake email subject
require 'mail'
msg_subject = Mail::Encodings.decode_encode(rus.encode(Encoding::KOI8_R), :encode)
# => "=?KOI8-R?B?0NLJ18XU?="


Mail::Encodings.value_decode("=?KOI8-R?B?0NLJ18XU?=")
=> "привет"
```

This will come back as UTF-8 (ruby default).  If you want to get it to KOI8_R you can encode again (or if you are feeling risky, .force_encoding).